# Twitter Bootsrap - Model - Fade is fading too much

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

Following this code my button works perfectly:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Fades and everything. I want to migrate this button to my websites nav bar. Once i insert the code into my navbar.. the fade function of the model fades out the entire body of the website. This prevents me from entering anything into the forms inside the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use that

```js
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

And remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from the button because this triggers the fading of the parent modal.

Comment: I figured it out... it was much more basic of a problem. I had my modal code inside the navbar, therfore the backdrop faded everything but the navbar.. to fix it i added the button in the navbar but had my modal code outside. Thanks tho!